# Modal piscando no mouseleave e mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho que fazer uma ação de quando passar o mouse em cima da imagem ela aparece em uma modal (bootstrap) com a imagem em um tamanho maior.

O problema é que ele fica piscando sem parar, dando hide e show quando estou com o mouse em cima.

Alguém saberia uma forma disso funcionar... já tentei de diversas formas e nada

```html
  <img  onmouseleave="$('#myModal<?php echo $v_disco_virtual[$i]['disco_virtual_id']?>').modal('hide');" onmouseenter=" $('#myModal<?php echo $v_disco_virtual[$i]['disco_virtual_id']?>').modal().show()" id="teste"   src="<?php echo $v_disco_virtual[$i]['disco_virtual_upload']; ?>" alt="image_produto.png">
```

Comment: Esse fiddle pode te ajudar (http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4556/) só n posto ele completo numa resposta pq n consegui colocar ele funcionando, basicamente ele usa bootstrap e é so add uma imagem na modal. caso não resolva é só avisar

Answer (score 1):

Conseui inserir o código, é só colocar uma imagem na modal que ta resolvido.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#test" ).hover(function() {
           $('.modal').modal({
        show: true
    });
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="test">Test</button>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <img src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6759/bcd6c5c19f07cd76b023bd0716f3e4f88887c0f9v2_128.jpg"/>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: kkk Show de bola a imagem, @Vinicius Sugiro que use o código de Renan e adapte ao seu caso.

Comment: Na verdade eu preciso que  a imagem desapareça quando tirar o mouse